# Help with Texas Instruments SN74LVT125

Tags: arduino, current, level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v

I am interfacing a 5V system to a 3.3V using the SN74LVT125 to shift down TTL voltage to 3.3V

My problem or my question is, Some of the input pins (the A ones) are being triggered by a 5V signal that comes directly from a phototransistor optocoupler. I couldn't find (or dont know where it is) how much current is the maximum allowed to send through the inputs of the SN74LVT125, or can I just put the 5V directly into the input pin without any resistor?

I tried searching the web but couldn't find any helpful information, I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Do you read the datasheets for parts you use in your design?

Comment: You're not 'sending' current 'through the inputs' of your '125. Its inputs are a high impedance which means that they will only draw a tiny current from whatever you connect to them (as long as you keep within the input voltage limits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the data sheet for the part. In the recommended operating conditions table they show that VI can normally be operated just fine up to 5.5V.

[image]

In the same data sheet also notice in the Electrical Characteristic table that the input current into the part will MAX out at 40uA with a VIN of 5.5V and VCC is either 0V or MAX VCC.

[image]

Comment: So that means I can input 5V directly from the power supply without any need to add a resistor?

Comment: That is what it means. But if you should choose to put a resistor in series with the input it would not be a problem as long as you don't put some thing in the megohms.

Answer (score 0):

From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvt125.pdf) for the TI SN74LVT125, the absolute maximum rating for signals applied to inputs are −0.5 V to 7 V. Generally, CMOS inputs are high impedance, so you would only expect microamps of input current, even with a +5V input. Since the datasheet says it operates with "5-V Input and Output Voltages With 3.3-V V_CC," I expect you can apply 5V directly to an input without any danger.

Comment: Awesome, thats what I just couldn't make out. I am just starting playing with some electronics so that's why I needed help.
Thanks a lot